# Algoritmo de backpropagation sin librerias en Python | Redes Neuronales

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

Estoy aprendiendo redes neuronales y pude implementar el forward pass, pero estoy teniendo problemas para el algoritmo de backpropagation. Me cuesta entender la forma que deben tener las matrices que alojan las derivadas de los pesos y biases para luego utilizarlos en el descenso del gradiente, y como calcular estas derivadas en retroceso. Esta es la red que quiero implementar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código que tengo hasta ahora es:

```
import numpy as np

class Layer:
    activation_func = None
    bias = None
    weights = None
    
    def __init__(self, inputs, neurons, activation_func):
        self.activation_func = activation_func
        self.weights = np.random.rand(inputs, neurons) * 2 - 1
        self.bias = np.random.rand(1, neurons) * 2 - 1

class Net:
    layers = []
    activation_func = None
    output = []
    adds = []
    inputs = []
    
    def __init__(self, inputs, topology, activation_func):
        #intputs: inputs number by neuron in the input layer
        #topology: each element it's the neurons number of each layer. Topology lenght it's the layers number 
        self.activation_func = activation_func
        layers = []
        for i in range(len(topology)):
            if i == 0:
                layers.append(Layer(inputs, topology[i], self.activation_func))
            else:
                layers.append(Layer(topology[i - 1], topology[i], self.activation_func))
        self.layers = layers
    
    def forward(self, inputs):
        output = []
        adds = []
        self.inputs = inputs
        for i, l in enumerate(self.layers):
            if i == 0:
                output_aux = [[]]
                adds_aux = [[]]
                for j, x in enumerate(self.inputs):
                    z = l.weights[j]@x.T + l.bias[0][j]
                    adds_aux[0].append(z[0])
                    act = self.activation_func(z[0])
                    output_aux[0].append(act)
                output.append(np.array(output_aux))
                adds.append(np.array(adds_aux))
            else:
                z = output[i - 1]@l.weights.T + l.bias
                adds.append(z)
                act = self.activation_func(z)
                output.append(act)
        self.output = output
        self.adds = adds
        return output[len(output) - 1]

sigm = lambda x: 1/(1 + np.e**(-x))

topology = [2, 2, 2, 2] 
inputs_net = 4
inputs_test = [np.array([[0.56, 0.75]]), np.array([[0.23, 0.41]])]

net = Net(inputs_net, topology, sigm)
result = net.forward(inputs_test)
```

La idea es que tome esos 4 valores fijos de entrada y devuelva 0 y 1 en las respectivas neuronas de salida. Cómo se construye el algoritmo de backpropagation para este ejemplo?

Comment: La pregunta es como medio amplia... vos queres que alguien construya el algoritmo por vos? o donde falla tu algoritmo?

Comment: Lo que me cuesta es entender como aplicar la regla de la cadena en el algoritmo, es decir, como ir calculando las derivadas de cada peso y bias e ir almacenandolas en las matrices. Intente construirlo pero no me salió. Se que (o tengo entendido que) para la ultima capa se calcula la derivada de la función de coste por la derivada de la función de activación por cada activación de la anteúltima capa (L - 1), pero después no se como ir retropropagando para calcular las derivadas de las capas ocultas

Comment: Me acuerdo haber hecho esto alguna vez. Como la dificultad claramente radica en el entendimiento del algoritmo, te recomiendo hacerlo en papel primero y luego implementar el metodo backward que almacene los gradientes de cada neurona y luego el metodo para actualizar los pesos. Segun recuerdo la dificultad era mas que nada calcular la derivada de las funciones de activacion y entender la regla de la cadena, pero una vez que tienes la lógica en el papel programarlo debería ser directo.

Comment: Al calculo matemático lo hice pero no estoy seguro de si está bien, lo publique en matematics stack exchange para ver si alguien me lo confirma https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3825193/backpropagation-calculus